# Mysql thread connected is 1-3 but experienced too many connections

Tags: mysql

Yesterday I can see in the log that within 1 minute timespan, there is alot of mysql errors with too many connections failures. I am running default setting: 151 for max_connections and have not experienced this before.

When checking current state, my thread connections is only 1 and up to 3 at max.

Should i increase my max_connections or did i just temporary suffer from a DDoS?

Note: It solved itself and worked immediately after that minute.

Update 2: It just happend again. I can see multiple errors within some seconds timeframe the error log. Why does this happen?

Comment: you dont mention how things are connecting to your mySQL - its common that many php/perl type connections people make the connection but dont close it once done, or leave it to php/perl to close it which happens "later" as a result, you can end up with a higher load of open connections than is expected becuase they havent closed yet

Comment: Can it have something to do that I recently have enabled multi_accept        on; for my nginx configuration?

Comment: @BugFinder Shouldn't I be able to see the connections when checking SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" -> Threads_Running which is 1 all the time? I am mysqli connecting once within the whole application.

Comment: show processlist is usually useful. is it one per app instance or one from your server only?

Comment: One from my server only @BugFinder

Comment: Have you tied the connections down to only allow your server? it maybe worth increasing it to 5 just as a precaution.

Comment: How do i increase this? @BugFinder And could that be the cause of too many connections error? I checked max_used_connections and can see "152" - so it did reach the max_connections, which i dont understand how when there is only 1 connection thread all the time when i check (and 3 at max).

Comment: its hard to be sure however, if your app is connected, and you are connected thats 2. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/update-max-connections-mysql/ 3 would seem a really low number.

Comment: What's connecting to your database ie are you using apache/nginx/tomcat. We'd also need to know if it's apache things like MPM configuration? Is mysql listening on localhost or an external IP?

Comment: You'd be amazed at how many hackers there are out there looking for PHP+MySQL machines that they can easily break into.  And especially Windows machines.  Some of the techniques involve throwing lots of queries very rapidly at the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decrease `max_connect_errors` to, say, 100.  This is a small protection against hackers.

`Threads_running` is always at least `1` because it includes your `SHOW`.

With `max_connections = 151`, `Max_used_connections = 152` means that 151 user connections came in, plus one "extra" connection was allowed and used.  For this reason, do *not* run your application as `root` (or any other `SUPER` user).

`GRANT ... ON your_database.* ...`, not `... ON *.* ...` for any application logins.  This seriously slows down hackers from getting at the `mysql` database.

`root` should be allowed only from `localhost`.  This is another safety measure.

If your web server has an "access" log, look at it.  You may see hundreds of similar looking hack attacks in a row.  And you may a similar set of them often.

Be sure to escape any data coming from html forms.  Do this as you build the `INSERTs`.  Without this, you are wide open for attack.

**Addenda**

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE Super_priv = 'Y';
```

will show you who has `SUPER`.  As a first cut, it should include only `host` values of `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, or `::1`, all of which are effectively localhost.  This does not prevent hackers from first hacking the client, which may also be on localhost.

This may list those with another way in:

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE Grant_priv = 'Y';
```

**Back to the question**

The Web server's (nginx's?) limit on the number of connections should be *less* than MySQL's `max_connections`.  This will stop hackers (and users) at the door, rather than letting them clog up *both* the web server and MySQL.

Even on a well running system, 20 is a reasonable max for how many should be allowed into the web server simultaneously.  If there are more, then they are probably stumbling over each other; it would be better to let a few get all the resources they need rather than take longer because of battling over resources.

Comment: max_connect_errors is only 10. Root is only allowed from localhost/local ip. I changed to database.* from *.* for the other users that my app uses. Are these root/SUPER because they have GRANT ALL PRIVILEGIES to a specific database?

Comment: No, `SUPER` is not included in `ON db.*`.  See addenda in a minute.

Comment: Added more -- "Back to the question" was based on experiences where high limits on both Apache and MySQL led to a calm system _suddenly_ melting down.  The on-call person could not do anything other than reboot.  (Not a pretty picture.)  That sounds like your symptoms.

Comment: I recently changed the webserver (nginx) to multi_accept on; which meant accepting multiple connections on the same time - and i think this was the cause.

Comment: But great safety tips!